# How to make periodic rest requests from Activity?

Tags: android, rest

One of my activity periodically updates nearby friends, which location is obtained from rest service

Currently I use postDelay:

```
private Runnable updateNearbyFriendsTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        list = api.getNearby(.....)

        handler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_RATE); 
    }
};
```

The problem is that postDelayed executed on UI thread, so this runnable task block ui with poor internet connection.

What is the right way to make periodic background rest requests from activity? I don't want to create service for that, because this rest method is used only in this activity.

**EDIT**

Currently switched to using ScheduledExecutor

```
this.scheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new UpdateNearbyFriendsTask(), 0, UPDATE_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

private class UpdateNearbyFriendsTask implements Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        list = api.getNearby(.....)

        runOnUiThread(.....)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is with creating a Service, even if it is only used for this activity.

That being said, have a look at the [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). It seems to do what you want.

Comment: There is no easy way to send data from Service to my activity. For service I have to create broadcast receiver and implement parcable for my data class. Don't you think that this is overhead?

Comment: If the service is a Bound Service, you can use the IBinder to send data to and from the activity. See the doc on Bound Services for details. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Comment: SO u suggest to create bound service with public method with listner parameter?

Answer (score 0):

How about BroadCast receiver using Alarm manager.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Since its a long running and on going task, would you want to write a Service or an Intent service which does the background job for you.
You can just ping the service whenever your time ticks and let the service do the network activity, freeing up the UI thread for something else. you can always query the service to know the status, or the service itself can respond back to your UI thread.

For ticking the timer, you can use the alarm manager, or perhaps something else (I am not good at any :P )